# Get records Relationship 1---N that can be null and filtered on child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get records from two table that are linked with fk. This fk can be null and the child table must have a filter.
I explain it with simple example.

```
Table Poet
IdPoet Number(5) 
NameVarchar2(250)

Table Poem 
IdPoem Number(5) 
IdPoet Number(5) FK 
Language Number(1) 
Text Varchar2(2000)
```

> The FK is relationship Poet and Poem
> Poet-1--------------N0---Poem
>
> Poem.IdPoet can be null.

I need to get all records from Poet that don't have poems, and poets that have poems with language=1 or language=2. Language 1 is more restrictive that 2. This mean that if there are a Poet that have 2 poems (one writes on language 1 and other write on language 2) must  show only record with language 1.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM POET, POEM
    WHERE POET.IDPOET = POEM.IDPOET(+)
    AND
    (
    (POEM.LANGUAGE IS NOT NULL AND POE.LANGUAGE = 1) OR
    (POEM.LANGUAGE IS NOT NULL AND POE.LANGUAGE = 2) OR
    (POEM.LANGUAGE IS = 1) OR
    (POEM.LANGUAGE IS = 2)
    )
```

This select shows Poets that don't have poems, that have 1 poem on language 1 or that have 1 poem on language 2. The problem is when poem have 2 poems, one on language 1 and other on language 2, then show 2 records, and i want to show only record with poem on language 1 because is more restrictive than 2.

Comment: You can try WHERE EXISTS clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using Oracle's [ROW_NUMBER()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions154.htm) analytic function:

```sql
SELECT Name, Text FROM (
  SELECT PT.Name, PM.Text, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PT.IdPoet ORDER BY PM.Language) RN
  FROM POET PT
  LEFT JOIN POEM PM ON (PT.IdPoet = PM.IdPoet)
  WHERE PM.Language IS NULL OR PM.Language IN (1, 2)
) WHERE RN = 1
```

Note that if there are multiple poems in language 1 for a single poet, it'll just pick whichever one is returned first from the database. You could add another field to the `ORDER BY` in the partition clause to sort by poem name, etc. first if you wanted.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1ecd/7)

---

**Edit:** Also, if you want the same behavior that alzaimar proposed (i.e., all poems from language 1 are shown), you can use the `DENSE_RANK()` function instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: This query was useful too but i like Terje D. answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but the idea is to create a list of all poets and if they have written something, all of their poems.

The Poets-table is left joined with the poems to include all poets

```
select distinct poets.Name,
       coalesce (l1.Text, l2.Text,'NONE') as Poem
  from Poets 
       left join (
         Poems l1
         full join Poems l2 
           on l1.IdPoet = l2.IdPoet
         )
         on Poets.IdPoet = l1.IdPoet

where 1l.Language = 1 and l2.Language=2
```

(untested)

However, if a poet has written more than one poem in one language, both are shown. I don't know whether this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select information on *every* poem with the *lowest* language value
for each poet, together with the poets that have no poems, this query should do:

```
SELECT * FROM Poet P
LEFT JOIN Poem ON Poem.IdPoet = P.IdPoet
where Poem.Language IS NULL
OR Poem.Language =
    (SELECT MIN(Language) As L1
     FROM Poem
     WHERE Poem.IdPoet = P.IdPoet
     GROUP BY Poem.IdPoet)
```

Here the lowest value for languageis asumed to be 1, and the query will also work language values higher than 2 is used.

Comment: This query do exact what i expected. Was good idea select min language. Thanks